# How to run multiple queries in Scylla using "Non Atomic" Batch/Pipeline

Tags: node.js, cassandra, datastax, scylla

I understand that Scylla allows batch statements like these.

```
BEGIN BATCH
<insert-stmt>/ <update-stmt>/ <delete-stmt>
APPLY BATCH
```

These statements have performance implications as it ensures atomicity. However, I simply have many insert statements which I want to perform from my `node` client in a single IO. Atomicity among these inserts is not needed. Any idea how I can do that? Can't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batching multiple inserts in Cassandra world usually is an antipattern (except when they go into one partition, see the [docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatchBadExample.html)).  When you're sending inserts into multiple partitions in one batch, the coordinator node will need to take care for taking data from this batch and sending them to nodes that are owning the data.  And this puts an additional load onto the coordinating node that first needs to backup the content of the batch just not to lose it if it crashes in the middle of execution, and then need to execute all operations, and wait for results of execution before sending it back to caller (see [this diagram](https://gist.github.com/alexott/2d5bf95a791450d5dc3e5f5ee11fc94c#gistcomment-3308508) to understand how so-called logged batch works).

When you don't need atomicity, then the best performance would be by sending multiple parallel inserts, and waiting for their execution - it will be faster, it will put less load onto nodes, and driver can use token-aware load balancing policy, so requests will be sent to nodes that own data (if you're using [prepared statements](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver#prepare-your-queries)). In node.js you can achieve this by using [Concurrent Execution API](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/4.6/features/concurrent-api/) - there are several variants of its usage, so it's better to look into the documentation to select what is best for your use case.

Comment: hi @Alex Ott , thank you for this.. I think I understand this now.. But another problem I faced was that my node IO process used to slow down drastically due to the huge number of IO operations (around 4k-5k IO op/sec). I fixed it by reducing the number of IO operations. Hence, I wanted to do a single IO instead of parallel IO.

Comment: You can try to combine multiple inserts that are targeting the same partition into the batches, but this will require an additional coding on your side.